# how to build a vapor app from an already existing database?

Tags: swift3, vapor

I have built a MySQL database with multiple tables and complex relationships, but when I go through the vapor documentation, specifically, in the building the model phase, there is a method for creating the table (that my model class will interact with).

```
static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.create("users") { users in
        users.id()
        users.string("name")
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to use it because the table that I already have contain foreign keys and types like DATETIME (which I don't know how to declare within the swift context.) is there a way to link my already built tables with vapor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhere Vapor (or more correctly Fluent, which is the database level of Vapor) is a bit limited.

Yes, you can use your existing tables. In your `prepare(_:)` method, you can simply leave the implementation empty without creating a table at all. You should also leave `revert(_:)` empty as well.

In your `init(node:in:)` initialiser and `makeNode(context:)` method, you will need to map between the column names and types in your table and the property types in your Swift model.

Answer (score 1):

In the model object class (User here), the `prepare` method can be left unimplemented since we don't need to create the tables explicitly from the code. So should be like

```
static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws { 
   ...
}
```

But should add a static variable named `entity` which will map the table name in db without model class, like following

```
final class User: Model {
    static let entity = "users"
    ...
}
```

And finally, we should add the model to the droplet's preparations array with `drop.preparations.append(User.self)`

So that we can use any existing table in a database which has complex relationships, to map from a model object in Vapor.